# Quickest way to solve a matrix one step at a time.

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I have a $14\times14$ matrix with a possibility of six states in each position The matrix is random each time. An example matrix would be:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
3&2&6&3&5&6&3&5&4&4&5&3&4&6\\
3&5&6&2&3&3&6&6&1&5&6&5&5&4\\
5&5&3&1&5&6&1&6&5&6&2&6&1&1\\
3&4&6&1&6&6&1&2&6&6&5&1&5&1\\
2&4&2&1&4&6&2&4&5&3&3&6&4&1\\
1&4&3&3&3&1&5&4&4&5&3&6&6&6\\
3&2&2&5&3&4&2&2&1&6&6&3&1&4\\
2&3&6&3&4&6&4&6&5&5&2&3&1&3\\
2&3&1&1&2&3&4&6&1&2&1&6&5&6\\
2&4&3&6&3&1&1&6&4&6&6&2&6&2\\
1&4&5&3&6&6&2&2&1&4&4&1&3&1\\
5&2&1&2&3&6&3&6&1&1&1&6&5&5\\
1&2&6&1&3&5&3&5&3&6&4&6&2&3\\
1&1&3&1&4&5&4&4&4&1&3&5&6&3
\end{pmatrix}$$

I want to be able to solve this matrix in the least amount of steps possible.

---

A step consists of picking a group of connected numbers that are the same. For instance the threes in the top left. And changing them to another number that it is touching. Like the fives, Which would result in the following Matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
5&2&6&3&5&6&3&5&4&4&5&3&4&6\\
5&5&6&2&3&3&6&6&1&5&6&5&5&4\\
5&5&3&1&5&6&1&6&5&6&2&6&1&1\\
3&4&6&1&6&6&1&2&6&6&5&1&5&1\\
2&4&2&1&4&6&2&4&5&3&3&6&4&1\\
1&4&3&3&3&1&5&4&4&5&3&6&6&6\\
3&2&2&5&3&4&2&2&1&6&6&3&1&4\\
2&3&6&3&4&6&4&6&5&5&2&3&1&3\\
2&3&1&1&2&3&4&6&1&2&1&6&5&6\\
2&4&3&6&3&1&1&6&4&6&6&2&6&2\\
1&4&5&3&6&6&2&2&1&4&4&1&3&1\\
5&2&1&2&3&6&3&6&1&1&1&6&5&5\\
1&2&6&1&3&5&3&5&3&6&4&6&2&3\\
1&1&3&1&4&5&4&4&4&1&3&5&6&3
\end{pmatrix}$$

Solving the matrix requires all numbers to be the same in the end:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5\\
5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5\\
5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5\\
5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5\\
5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5\\
5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5\\
5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5\\
5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5\\
5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5\\
5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5\\
5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5\\
5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5\\
5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5\\
5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5&5
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: You're trying to hack Flood Fill, aren't you? :)

Comment: I have actually never heard of that. Lol this was a question a few classmates of mine were arguing about and I kind-of  joined in.

Comment: It seems like it's part art.  Each move that gives you the most "in-roads" to other parts of the matrix seems to do pretty well.  This might be quantified by looking ahead a move or two to see which is the most favorable outcome.

Comment: I tried assigning a weight to each section, defined by the size of the section and then evaluating all combinations possible for three steps ahead. But it didn't seem like the most effecient method to me.

Comment: Fundamentally this is a graph theory problem.  The size of each region is irrelevant to the number of steps: you need only consider its connections to other regions.  I wonder if the greedy algorithm of always choosing a move which merges the most regions together would be effective.

Comment: This is what I am trying to implement right now. But I'm having trouble coming up with a way to calculate with a program how big each region is.

Comment: @snocavotia Finding connected components is a very routine computer science problem.  It isn't really suited for MSE (the question of the optimal algorithm is more fitting, but still very CS-oriented).  I reiterate, it doesn't matter how *big* each region is, except indirectly: larger regions can potentially have more neighbours.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get away from the grid. I suggest the following approach:

Start with 196 regions, each corresponding to one of the entries in your matrix.

Each region has a list of other regions that it is adjacent to. Initially each this will be two, three or four regions depending on where in the grid the region is.

Each region has a colour, which is equivalent to the state number you have given them.

Initial phase: identifying connected regions.

Start with the first region. Check each adjacent region to see if it has the same colour. If it does, then add its list of adjacent regions to the list your first region has (strictly the union rather than sum) and delete the region. Continue through the list of adjacent regions until the first region has no adjacent regions that have the same colour.

Move on to the second region. Etc.

This phase will give you all the separate regions and their adjacent regions. You are then ready to move on to solving your problem. By the way, you will probably want to maintain a list of which cell is in which region at each step so that you can translate back to the grid representation at any stage, but it is not needed to help solve the problem.

Solving phase: here you want to choose two regions that are adjacent. You then need to decide which colour is going to continue into the next step, then combine them into one region with that colour. Check if any of the adjacent regions are also that colour, in which case they will also become part of the larger region. You only need to check regions that are adjacent to the region whose colour is being changed. The region whose colour is not being changed will not have any adjacent regions of the same colour to it.

To choose pairings, I don't know, but you could look for the region with fewest adjacent regions (consider the extreme case of an enclave) or the region with the most.

In choosing which colour to make the combined region, I think maybe the mot prevalent colour overall?